# SQL on Oracle error

Tags: sql

(songs table)

```
insert into albums values('Queen', 'Keep Yourself Alive','Brian','1973')
insert into albums values('Queen', 'Liar', 'Freddie','1973')
insert into albums values('Queen II', 'The Fairy Fellers Master Stroke', 'Freddie','1974')
insert into albums values('Queen II', 'Funny How Love Is', 'Freddie', '1974')
insert into albums values('A Night At The Opera', 'Youre My Best Friend', 'John', '1975')
insert into albums values('Jazz', 'Dead On Time', 'Brian', '1978')
insert into albums values('The Game', 'Another One Bites The Dust', 'John', '1980');
```

---

```
create table albums(
album_title varchar2(50),
song_title varchar2(50),
band_member varchar2(30),
year int(4));
```

I keep on getting this error

```
SQL> @songs;
insert into albums values('The Game', 'Another One Bites The Dust', 'John', '1980')
                                                                            *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01861: literal does not match format string
```

What is wrong with my commands?

Comment: `int(4)` is not a valid data type for Oracle, so your CREATE TABLE does not work. And you should not specify numeric values as string literals using single quotes. And Florin has a good point as well: each statement has to be delimited with a `;`

Answer (score 1):

With Oracle characters between single quote marks are STRINGS, try removing it to the year field or using the function TO_NUMBER()

Examples:
`insert into albums values('The Game', 'Another One Bites The Dust', 'John', 1980)`

or

`insert into albums values('The Game', 'Another One Bites The Dust', 'John', TO_NUMBER('1980'))`

**Edit**: 
*(Answer from comments below)*
You need to change the datatype of the column year, try this:
`alter table albums modify( year number(4) ) ;`

Comment: SQL> @songs;
insert into albums values('The Game', 'Another One Bites The Dust', 'John', 1980)
                                                                            *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected DATE got NUMBER

Comment: Try creating your table this way instead:

`create table albums(
album_title varchar2(50),
song_title varchar2(50),
band_member varchar2(30),
year number(4));`

(Note the change from int to number)

Comment: SQL> @songs;
insert into albums values('The Game', 'Another One Bites The Dust', 'John',1977)
                                                                           *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected DATE got NUMBER

Comment: You need to change the datatype for the column year, try this:
`truncate table albums` and 
`alter table albums
modify(
year number(4))
;`

Comment: SQL> alter table albums modify( year number(4)) ;

Table altered.

SQL> @songs;

1 row created.

SQL> describe songs;
 Name                                      Null?    Type
 ----------------------------------------- -------- ----------------------------
 SONG_ID                                   NOT NULL VARCHAR2(4)
 SONG_DATE                                          DATE
 SONG_TITLE                                         VARCHAR2(225)
 SONG_ALBUM                                         VARCHAR2(225)

SQL> select * from songs;

no rows selected

Comment: did you mean `select * from albums` instead from songs?

Comment: because you have only one row on that table :) , if you can insert rows sucessfully, then your question is solved :)

Answer (score 0):

I didn't have done a lot with oracle but the year is defined as an int, so shouldn't you pass 1980 instead of '1980', should you ?

Comment: SQL> @songs;
insert into albums values('The Game', 'Another One Bites The Dust', 'John', 1980)
                                                                            *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected DATE got NUMBER
It didn't work. I got this error

Comment: @illest: Are you quite sure that `albums` is defined as you've shown above?

Comment: Are you sure that t he column is a int ? The Exception message makes me feel like there is a date column....

Comment: it was 'date' before but it still keeps giving me the same error. What should I change?

Answer (score 0):

If you define your table with `year number(4)`, and put `;` after every insert, everything should work fine.